# I want to automate Azure ARM/ASM VM start/stop by just sending a mail to specific person for any VM

Tags: azure, webhooks, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation

Currently, In **Azure ARM** I have deployed

- Automation account with a **PowerShell Runbook** consist of script to start/stop a Virtual Machine.
- Created a **Webhook** for PowerShell Runbook
- Created a **Logic App** and added the connection to **O365 account** to get access of mail box. Whenever a mail will come from a particular user (example@contoso.com), the logic app will extract the keyword from mail's subject.

Right now, I am able to start/stop the VM by just sending a mail along with a Keyword `Start VM Name` successfully.Logic app is extracting the keyword from mail's subject,then if the subject will match the condition then it will trigger a HTTP Webhook defined in logic app which will further trigger the PowerShell Runbook and then the VM will start/stop.

Currently I can start/stop a single VM only as I am not able to pass the value to Runbook so, I am using static value inside the Runbook, but I want to implement it for Multiple VMs by passing the Keyword from Logic App to PowerShell Runbook so that I can use the keyword inside PowerShell to perform the action accordingly.

Please find the screen shot of Logic App:

[image: Screen Shot of Logic App Designer in Azure Portal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an azure automation connector that will let you pass in parameters and leverage hybrid workers for runbooks. Will be global by end of week - you can access today in some regions like Brazil South

Comment: thanks jaffhollan. but as of now i got an another way to pass the Keyword (like VM name) as an object using **HTTP Webhook**. i have defined the object using keyword sent by sender (who wants to start/stop the VM) in **Http Webhook body**  and then extracted the **Keyword** inside the Runbook by accepting the _Webhook Data_ and performing action accordingly.